# Android Studio displaying compilation errors suddenly for no reason

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Android Studio is suddenly displaying compilation errors for all the java files in my project today. However gradle build is successful.It worked perfect till yesterday.

I restarted, did a project clean and made sure that SDK and JDK locations in the project structure are valid. I am bit surprised on facing this issue, any thoughts?

```
Android Studio version is 1.4
```

Error log:

```
12-15 20:39:30.281 122-143/? E/Vold: Cannot open CDROM lunfile
12-15 20:39:30.501 399-432/? E/NotificationService: Ignoring notification with icon==0: Notification(pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=nullnull defaults=0x0 flags=0x62 kind=[null])
12-15 20:40:06.291 122-143/? E/Vold: Cannot open CDROM lunfile
12-15 20:40:06.581 399-432/? E/NotificationService: Ignoring notification with icon==0: Notification(pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=nullnull defaults=0x0 flags=0x62 kind=[null])
12-15 20:40:49.841 122-143/? E/Vold: Cannot open CDROM lunfile
12-15 20:40:50.091 399-432/? E/NotificationService: Ignoring notification with icon==0: Notification(pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=nullnull defaults=0x0 flags=0x62 kind=[null])
12-15 20:45:02.161 122-143/? E/Vold: Cannot open CDROM lunfile
12-15 20:45:02.411 399-432/? E/NotificationService: Ignoring notification with icon==0: Notification(pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=nullnull defaults=0x0 flags=0x62 kind=[null])
12-15 20:46:23.421 19934-19934/? E/PeriodStatsTracker: Couldn't find package statistics when removing location request.
12-15 20:46:23.861 576-576/? E/copybit: Error opening frame buffer errno=13 (Permission denied)
12-15 20:46:27.131 576-576/? E/copybit: Error opening frame buffer errno=13 (Permission denied)
12-15 20:46:27.311 122-143/? E/Vold: Cannot open CDROM lunfile
12-15 20:46:27.521 399-432/? E/NotificationService: Ignoring notification with icon==0: Notification(pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=nullnull defaults=0x0 flags=0x62 kind=[null])
12-15 20:46:28.311 19934-19934/? E/PeriodStatsTracker: Couldn't find package statistics when removing location request.
12-15 20:46:30.711 122-143/? E/Vold: Cannot open CDROM lunfile
12-15 20:46:30.891 399-432/? E/NotificationService: Ignoring notification with icon==0: Notification(pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=nullnull defaults=0x0 flags=0x62 kind=[null])
12-15 20:46:35.101 18257-21009/? E/MediaProvider: no database for attached volume content://media/external
12-15 20:46:35.981 23308-21063/? E/scaladoUtil: Scalado_LoadImage:  caps_getImageTypeFromHdrFile fail 14
12-15 20:46:35.991 23308-21063/? E/HtcModel: [Cursor2ImageMapper] can't decode file from: /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/browser-images/1446883765647615073691.jpg, mImgSizeLimit: 10485760
12-15 20:46:35.991 23308-21063/? E/scaladoUtil: Scalado_LoadImage:  caps_getImageTypeFromHdrFile fail 14
12-15 20:46:36.001 23308-21063/? E/HtcModel: [Cursor2ImageMapper] can't decode file from: /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/browser-images/1446883742515-2033614842.jpg, mImgSizeLimit: 10485760
12-15 20:46:36.001 23308-21063/? E/scaladoUtil: Scalado_LoadImage:  caps_getImageTypeFromHdrFile fail 14
12-15 20:46:36.001 23308-21063/? E/HtcModel: [Cursor2ImageMapper] can't decode file from: /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/browser-images/1446883624346-2033614842.jpg, mImgSizeLimit: 10485760
12-15 20:46:38.821 18257-21009/? E/MediaProvider: no database for attached volume content://media/external
12-15 20:46:52.321 20386-21055/? E/ImageDecoder: loadFromFilePathToBitmap() NG - loadFromFilePath -2  /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/browser-images/1446883624346-2033614842.jpg
12-15 20:46:52.321 20386-21055/? E/ImageDecoder: loadFromFilePathToBitmap() NG - loadFromFilePath -2  /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/browser-images/1446883742515-2033614842.jpg
12-15 20:46:52.321 20386-21055/? E/ImageDecoder: loadFromFilePathToBitmap() NG - loadFromFilePath -2  /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/browser-images/1446883765647615073691.jpg
12-15 20:47:07.261 23308-21093/? E/scaladoUtil: Scalado_LoadImage:  caps_getImageTypeFromHdrFile fail 14
12-15 20:47:07.261 23308-21093/? E/HtcModel: [Cursor2ImageMapper] can't decode file from: /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/browser-images/1446883765647615073691.jpg, mImgSizeLimit: 10485760
12-15 20:47:07.271 23308-21093/? E/scaladoUtil: Scalado_LoadImage:  caps_getImageTypeFromHdrFile fail 14
12-15 20:47:07.271 23308-21093/? E/HtcModel: [Cursor2ImageMapper] can't decode file from: /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/browser-images/1446883742515-2033614842.jpg, mImgSizeLimit: 10485760
12-15 20:47:07.271 23308-21093/? E/scaladoUtil: Scalado_LoadImage:  caps_getImageTypeFromHdrFile fail 14
12-15 20:47:07.281 23308-21093/? E/HtcModel: [Cursor2ImageMapper] can't decode file from: /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/browser-images/1446883624346-2033614842.jpg, mImgSizeLimit: 10485760
12-15 20:47:07.931 18257-21009/? E/MediaProvider: no database for attached volume content://media/external
12-15 20:47:09.691 23308-21101/? E/scaladoUtil: Scalado_LoadImage:  caps_getImageTypeFromHdrFile fail 14
12-15 20:47:09.691 23308-21101/? E/HtcModel: [Cursor2ImageMapper] can't decode file from: /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/browser-images/1446883765647615073691.jpg, mImgSizeLimit: 10485760
12-15 20:47:09.701 23308-21101/? E/scaladoUtil: Scalado_LoadImage:  caps_getImageTypeFromHdrFile fail 14
12-15 20:47:09.701 23308-21101/? E/HtcModel: [Cursor2ImageMapper] can't decode file from: /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/browser-images/1446883742515-2033614842.jpg, mImgSizeLimit: 10485760
12-15 20:47:09.711 23308-21101/? E/scaladoUtil: Scalado_LoadImage:  caps_getImageTypeFromHdrFile fail 14
12-15 20:47:09.711 23308-21101/? E/HtcModel: [Cursor2ImageMapper] can't decode file from: /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/browser-images/1446883624346-2033614842.jpg, mImgSizeLimit: 10485760
12-15 20:47:23.281 20386-21081/? E/ImageDecoder: loadFromFilePathToBitmap() NG - loadFromFilePath -2  /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/browser-images/1446883624346-2033614842.jpg
12-15 20:47:23.291 20386-21081/? E/ImageDecoder: loadFromFilePathToBitmap() NG - loadFromFilePath -2  /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/browser-images/1446883742515-2033614842.jpg
12-15 20:47:23.291 20386-21081/? E/ImageDecoder: loadFromFilePathToBitmap() NG - loadFromFilePath -2  /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/browser-images/1446883765647615073691.jpg
12-15 20:48:32.751 132-21107/? E/OMXNodeInstance: OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0x437c7180 successful
12-15 20:48:32.751 132-21107/? E/OMXNodeInstance: OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0x437c7390 successful
12-15 20:48:32.751 132-21107/? E/OMXNodeInstance: OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0x437c74d0 successful
12-15 20:48:32.751 132-21107/? E/OMXNodeInstance: OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0x437c75f8 successful
12-15 20:48:32.751 132-132/? E/AudioPolicyManagerBase: getOutput() IOProfile is null.
12-15 20:48:32.751 132-132/? E/AudioPolicyManagerBase: getOutput() IOProfile is null.
12-15 20:48:32.751 132-132/? E/AudioPolicyManagerBase: getOutput() IOProfile is null.
12-15 20:48:32.751 132-132/? E/AudioPolicyManagerBase: getOutput() IOProfile is null.
12-15 20:48:35.091 132-21107/? E/MP3Extractor: Unable to resync. Signalling end of stream.
12-15 20:48:42.741 132-21107/? E/OMXNodeInstance: OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0x437c7010 successful
12-15 20:48:42.741 132-21107/? E/OMXNodeInstance: OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0x43686f10 successful
12-15 20:48:42.741 132-21107/? E/OMXNodeInstance: OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0x43686e40 successful
12-15 20:48:42.741 132-21107/? E/OMXNodeInstance: OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0x43686ca0 successful
12-15 20:48:42.741 132-21107/? E/OMXNodeInstance: OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0x437c70e0 successful
12-15 20:48:42.741 132-21107/? E/OMXNodeInstance: OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0x41633fb0 successful
12-15 20:48:42.741 132-21107/? E/OMXNodeInstance: OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0x41633ee8 successful
12-15 20:48:42.741 132-21107/? E/OMXNodeInstance: OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0x41634330 successful
12-15 20:52:45.161 21126-21126/? E/Trace: error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-15 20:52:45.881 21126-21126/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.Notification$Action$Builder', referenced from method efj.a
12-15 20:52:45.951 21126-21126/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method efj.a
12-15 20:52:46.091 21126-21126/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.Notification$Action$Builder', referenced from method efj.a
12-15 20:52:46.151 21126-21126/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method efj.a
12-15 20:52:46.151 21126-21126/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.transition.TransitionSet', referenced from method efj.a
12-15 20:52:46.151 21126-21126/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method efj.a
12-15 20:52:46.161 21126-21126/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method efj.a
12-15 20:52:46.211 21126-21126/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.RemoteInput[]', referenced from method efj.a
12-15 20:52:46.261 21126-21126/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method efj.b
12-15 20:52:46.871 21126-21126/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method eer.a
12-15 20:52:48.951 19934-21166/? E/SQLiteLog: (5) statement aborts at 1: [PRAGMA journal_mode=TRUNCATE;] 
12-15 20:52:48.981 19934-21165/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.fitness.store.g.t.a
12-15 20:52:49.001 19934-21165/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.fitness.store.g.t.k
12-15 20:57:14.591 19934-21183/? E/SQLiteLog: (5) statement aborts at 1: [PRAGMA journal_mode=TRUNCATE;] 
12-15 20:57:19.821 19934-21197/? E/SQLiteLog: (5) statement aborts at 1: [PRAGMA journal_mode=TRUNCATE;] 
12-15 21:00:43.931 19934-19934/? E/PeriodStatsTracker: Couldn't find package statistics when removing location request.
12-15 21:00:44.541 576-576/? E/copybit: Error opening frame buffer errno=13 (Permission denied)
12-15 21:00:44.871 122-143/? E/Vold: Cannot open CDROM lunfile
12-15 21:00:44.991 399-432/? E/NotificationService: Ignoring notification with icon==0: Notification(pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=nullnull defaults=0x0 flags=0x62 kind=[null])
12-15 21:00:47.761 18257-21212/? E/MediaProvider: no database for attached volume content://media/external
```

Comment: Can you post the error logs ?

Comment: Android Studio is currently in stable version 1.5.1. They have fix a bunch of problems. I recommend you to update to 1.5.1.

Comment: @MidhunMP Posted error logs..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue a couple of months ago.

- Navigate to taskbar menu
- Go to Build->Rebuild Project
- Go to Build->Clean Project (you did that already but do it after rebuilding)
- Go to Tools->Android->Sync with gradle files
- You can also try to go to File->Invalidate Caches/Restart

This worked for me.